Equal UV Unwrapping issue
I've always had difficulty with UV's, however I'm struggling to unwrap this one in particular.
Each are different panels, I can manually and smart unwrap. However I always get the same result, the panels towards the center have smaller uv's compared to the outside.
Scaling the uv results in the uv extending outside the box bounds (not sure if this is acceptable?
Not sure on how to go about averaging the uv scale to make them all proportionate?



Are these all one object or several separate objects?

Several, all unwrapped separately

If you select all the objects and once and then Tab into edit mode, you can then press F3 to search for operators in the UV window and find "Average Islands Scale" which should even them out.

yeah that looks like it works, but it does take the uv's outside of the uv box. Isn't that an issue?

@KinergyJ you can then "pack islands" or just scale them down until they fit again

@KinergyJ It depends on what your plan is for the mesh. UV space repeats infinitely from 0-1 in all directions. If you're using only tiling textures for this mesh then you're free to scale them to fit your needs. If you were going to bake a normal map then you would have to pack things more carefully. That's another topic tho.
